# What is the fr signature in zip files?

Tags: zip, hexadecimal

I use the 101 editor for easily editing zip file's properties. I noticed there being one of the "properties" in a structure called ZIPFILERECORD. The structure has the value of the name of contents of the zip file. But then there is frSignature, which is a char array making **PK34**. Does anyone know what this **frSignature** does?

Comment: It appears to be a well-known value. It’s always `\x50\x4b\x01\x02`

Comment: @DanielB Well, I don't know it. And also, it is `\x50\x4b\x01\x04`. The final byte is a `\x04` not a `\x02`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#File_headers) it identifies the following record as a file record. It’s a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) of sorts.